# Firefox alt key preventDefault not working

Tags: javascript, angular, firefox

I am working on an Angular application, and I need to listen for keypresses to override default behavior. In particular, I want to disable the default `ALT` key behavior in Firefox where the menu toolbar appears at the top. The following code works in Chrome but not in Firefox:

```
  @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(e: any) {
    if (e.key === 'Alt' || e.altKey) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      return;
    }
```

**Note:** I have seen several threads online regarding similar issues with Firefox, but none of them were Angular projects, so maybe the solution to my problem requires some Angular insight?

Comment: try `e.which === 18`

Comment: How is the visibility of the menu bar related to your project? Why on Earth would you want to restrict the user from accessing the menu? It seems current implementation of FF doesn't allow user scripts to hijack the menu show/hide behaviour and I think that's right.

Comment: @marekful I should have added that I have a display where the user should have the ability to zoom in and out of the display using alt-scroll. For whatever reason that functionality is being handled by a separate component and works perfectly, I just need to preventdefault behavior in this global event listener (separate component). Since the alt key menu bar will certainly change the focus, breaking our zoom functionality.

Comment: Ctrl+wheel handles the zoom in FF, it's "built-in". Not good?

Comment: The Ctrl+wheel zooms the entire browser but our application has a display that has content in the body of the document that we want to zoom in and out of using the alt+wheel. I just wanted to know why this functionality differs from FF and Chrome and if there is a way to go around these differences.

Answer (score 0):

I only had course for angular2 months ago, but I made the following snippet in this course. (I only use Angular [1])
The only difference is that instead of e: any i used event: KeyboardEvent. and I imported the HostListener

```
import {HostListener} from '@angular/core';
@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
handleKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.key === 'Alt' || event.altKey) {
         event.preventDefault();
         event.stopPropagation();
         return;
     }
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem, but I cannot test it.